# how can I resolve unauthorized error flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a flask app on my RPi to control Leds and I implemented a user login interface. Everything was working fine, but now everytime I try to connect to an account I get
"Unauthorized
The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."
I also get an error now when the user is not existing or when I enter the wrong credentials "TypeError: The view function for 'login' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

The error is driving me crazy to be honest because I didn't even touch the code and I don't really know where the issue is.

Thank you in advance for your time and patience.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect, \
    url_for, request, session, flash, g, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy, SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from functools import wraps

database = "credientals.db"


app = Flask( __name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///{db}'.format(db=database)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "You can't touch what you can't see"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password_hashed = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '' % self.username

def create_db():
    db.create_all()

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

@app.route("/signup/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if not (username and password):
            flash('cannot signup: credentials empty!')
            return redirect(url_for('signup'))
        else:
            username = username.strip()
            password = password.strip()

        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password, method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=16)
        new = User(username = username, password_hashed = hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new)

        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
            flash("User {u} already taken!".format(u=username))
            return redirect(url_for("signup"))
        flash("Account has been created!")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("signup.html")

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if not (username and password):
            flash("Username or Password cannot be empty.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            username = username.strip()
            password = password.strip()

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hashed, password):
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for("user", username=username))
        else:
            flash("Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```